# Django + matplotlib : image is not refreshed after new figsave()

Tags: django, matplotlib

I have a model that calls matplotlib to create and save a figure.

When the user creates a new object instance, matplotlib creates and save a fig and I return to the user a page that includes the fig.This works.

When the user edits the object instance : matplotlib creates a new figure that overrides the existing figure file, this works : I have checked that the figure file is updated on the server.

My problem is that the image is not updated in the page returned to the user : the user has to simply refresh the page and then the image is updated. this happens not always : sometimes the image is updated whithout need for refreshing.

I wonder if perhaps the page is displayed to fast when the new matplotlib fig is not already saved on the disk.

Any idea ?

models.py (extract)

```
class Appareil(models.Model):


    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    ...............(other fields)
    .............

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.picture_file_name=figure(self.filed1,self.field2)       


        super(Appareil, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py (extract)

```
def figure(field1, field2) :

   #Init figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10),dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

   #various matplot commands
   #...........................

   #file_png = etc....

    picture_file_name = "/static/images/" + file_png + ".png"

    plt.savefig("static/images/" + fichier_png + ".png", transparent=True)

    return (picture_file_name)
```

template (extract)

```
<img src="{{appareil.picture_file_name}}" />
```

Comment: I haven't find a solution to display the page only after the image is overriden.

As a workaround, I create a new image on saving and I add the timestamp to the image file name.